# Como carregar todas as funções de uma pasta?

Tags: funções, r

Suponha que na pasta "D:" tenha diversas funções que uso num projeto.
Como fazer para carregar todas essas funções com um script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talvez seja interessante criar uma função que leia os arquivos de uma pasta arbitrária, assim você pode reaproveitar o código várias vezes. Para deixar o código mais limpo, é possível usar o `sapply` ao invés de um loop com `for` (mas nesse caso não faz muita diferença, vou usar para exemplificar):

```
lerFuncoes <- function(pasta){
  files <-list.files(pasta) #pega os arquivos
  sapply(sapply(pasta, paste, files, sep=""),source, echo=FALSE)
  NULL
}
```

Daí é só usar `lerFuncoes(pasta)`.

Comment: O que é uma pasta arbitrária?

Answer (score 2):

Para carregar as funções pode ser utilizado um for-loop onde estão as funções que se deseja carregar.

```
setwd("D:")    
funcoes<-list.files()
len<-length(funcoes)
for (i in 1:len)
{source(funcoes[i])      
}
```